# Scenekit - What is consuming more GPU-capacity: one node+geometry with concavePolyhedron, or 5 subnodes with boundingBox geometries?

Tags: geometry, gpu, shapes, scenekit

As I wrote previously, I am using tunnels in my game app, which are made up from a number of ring-shaped parts, each containing 20 or more planar elements. In order to detect a collision with the ship, all planes have a planar geometry (boundingBox) attached.

I found a nice way to deform the tunnels to give them a more natural appearance. In this process, I also found it to be a good opportunity to merge several planes to reduce the number of subnodes (e.g. 5-->1, incl. the attached geometries) to save GPU capacity. On the other hand, this requires the use of concavePolyhedrons instead of the boundingBoxes which I currently apply.

But as the placing of the combined parts is much easier and more precise, I am thinking of using this generally. Now I am wondering if some kind of ratio is available (or easy to evaluate) concerning the calculatory load of a concavePolyhedron in relation to a boundingBox or convexHull?

I am well aware that this depends very much on the complexity of the new shapes. Yet I am thinking that if the ratio of boBox:cvHull:ccPolhed wasn't at least 1:10:100 (or something alike), the designers at Apple wouldn't have bothered to create all three types.

So assuming (just as an example) that I only use simple boxes, but declare them as convexHulls or even concavePolyhedrons (instead of said boundingBoxes), how much more capacity would be consumed in addition? I would like to have the game running smoothly on older devices as well, so I am very eager to know the least capacity-consuming method.

Maybe someone has a rule of thumb in this matter?

Comment: So I did implement as I was writing above, and luckily, the app is still running at 60fps.